# Search based on date and time varchar datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12ff4/1)

```
CREATE TABLE STUDY
(
  [ID][INT],
  STUDY_DATE VARCHAR(40),
  START_TIME VARCHAR (40),
  END_TIME VARCHAR (40)

)

INSERT INTO STUDY VALUES(1,'2013-12-26','11:30:00','11:31:00')

SELECT 
    STUDY_DATE,
    START_TIME,
    END_TIME
FROM 
    STUDY
WHERE
    STUDY_DATE>='2013-12-25' 
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),START_TIME,108)>='18:41:34' 
    AND STUDY_DATE<='2013-12-26'
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),END_TIME,108)<='12:41:34'
```

Here when start_time is greater than end time then it gives me zero result.
What should i do

Comment: Your `START_TIME` is `11:30:00` and you are checking if it is `>=` to `18:41:34` and it is not.

Comment: i have to get in between records where date between'2013-12-25' and '2013-12-26' and stat_time and end_time between '18:41:34' and '12:41:34'

Comment: my query fails when start_time is greater than end time then it gives me zero result.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the recommended way to handle dates and times, but if you can't change the datatypes:

```
SELECT
    STUDY_DATE,
    START_TIME,
    END_TIME
FROM
    STUDY
WHERE
    CAST(STUDY_DATE + ' ' + START_TIME AS DATETIME) >= '2013-12-25 18:41:34' AND
    CAST(STUDY_DATE + ' ' + END_TIME AS DATETIME) <= '2013-12-26 12:41:34'
```

---ORIG---

You should be a little more respectful of the appropriate data types, if you can. There are alternatives to your design - one might be:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDY
(
ID INT, -- Consider PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)?
START_TIME DATETIME,
END_TIME DATETIME
);
```

That way you could use dates/times more appropriately:

```
SELECT * FROM STUDY WHERE START_TIME >= '12/25/2013 18:41:34' AND END_TIME <= '12/26/2013 12:41:34'
```

Comment: I can only guess that changing the data type isn't a possibility, but man that's harsh either way.

Comment: Nicarus dont want to change datatype

Comment: @Means - you should clarify that in your question.

Comment: Nicarus when i have to find records between time slab 11:00:00 to 11:18:00 from all dates how should i manage above query

Comment: Text is not the way to do this. You should research DATEPART: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to group the start time with your eartlier date and the end time with your second date.

If so you can do this:

```
SELECT STUDY_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME
FROM STUDY
WHERE
STUDY_DATE BETWEEN  '2013-12-25' AND '2013-12-26'
AND 
(
  (STUDY_DATE = '2013-12-25' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),START_TIME,108)>='18:41:34')
  OR
  (STUDY_DATE = '2013-12-26' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),END_TIME,108)<='12:41:34')
)
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12ff4/11)

Comment: It's probably not likely in this case, but wouldn't some different collations render different results since it is text that is being compared and not date/time values?

Comment: @Nikhil in the `WHERE` clause put `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),START_TIME,108)>='11:00:00' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),END_TIME,108)<='11:18:00'`